# How to reload a page in javascript while limiting the count of number of times a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript

What I aiming for is - to reload a page every time the reload button is clicked 
 (using javascript function : window.location.reload ();) and also keep track of number of times the button (Retake Test) is clicked. The page should reload only for the first three clicks. If the button is clicked more than three times, it should lead to a different page

**Code**:

```
   <div class = "text-center"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-success 
    btn-block" onclick ="myCheck();">Retake Test</button>
```

and here is the solution I came of with (which obviously did not work)

```
<script>
var count = 0;
 function myCheck () {
count = count+1;
 if (count < 3) {
    window.location.reload();
    }
else {
    document.write ("YYY");
    }
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

```
<script>
 localStorage.setItem('count', '0');
 function myCheck () {
  localStorage.setItem('count',  +(localStorage.getItem('count'))+ 1)
    if (+(localStorage.getItem('count')) < 3) {
      window.location.reload();
    }
    else {
      document.write ("YYY");
    }
 }
 </script>
```

This is a hurried attempt , you can make your code more succinct ofcourse !

ADDITIONAL NOTE: Also avoid using inline javascript like `onclick ="myCheck();"`
use `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: That just again resets the variable to 0 as soon as the page gets reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Since your variables get reset by reloading the page, you maybe want to save `count` somewhere else. Cookies would be a useful option, in modern browser one could also use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

However maybe the solution you are looking for is reloading only a part of your webpage via AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Your counts are getting lost on page reload. Use localstorage or cookies

```
"use strict";

function myCheck() {
  var count = localStorage.getItem('count') || 0;
  if (count < 3) {
    localStorage.setItem('count', (count += 1) )
    return window.location.reload();
  }
  // more than or equal to 3 times
  document.write("YYY");
}
```

Comment: @SidBrown maybe select it as best answer then :)

Comment: i do not have enough credits to select this as the best ans

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage.setItem and localStorage.getItem

```
 <script>
 var count=typeof localastrorage.getItem('count')!="null"? localstorage.getItem('count'):0;
function myCheck () {
   localStorage.setItem("count",count);
count = count+1;
 if (count < 3) {
    window.location.reload();
    }
else {
    document.write ("YYY");
    }
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: What's the need for type checking?

Comment: To decide that if the local storage variable has a value so set it to the count variable if not for some reason with in the upload of page so it will be zero

Comment: localStorage.getItem('SomeThingThatDoesntExist"'), returns null instead of undefined.

Comment: Yes sory for that